# Problemas con ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

estoy con un problema. Hice un ViewPager con 3 pantallas.
Hasta ahí estaba todo bien, el problema vino cuando quise programar sobre una de las pantallas y no entiendo porque me tira error en algo tan simple como que un botón se vuelve invisible al presionarlo por ejemplo. Probé lo mismo sin el ViewPager y funciona.

Acá les dejo el código de lo que tengo, disculpen si la pregunta es tonta, aprendí hace poco como usar ViewPager y todavía hay cosas que no entiendo.

MainActivity (el que contiene al ViewPager):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;

private RelativeLayout page1;
private RelativeLayout page2;
private RelativeLayout page3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainPageAdapter());
}

class MainPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position)
    {
        View page = null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                if (page1 == null)
                {
                    page1 = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_pantalla_tienda, null);
                }
                page = page1;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (page2 == null)
                {
                    page2 = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_pantalla_principal, null);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
                page = page2;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (page3 == null)
                {
                    page3 = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_pantalla_jardin, null);
                }
                page = page3;
                break;
        }

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);


        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view)
    {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

}
```

}

El código de la pantalla sobre la que quería trabajar

```
public class pantalla_principal extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla_principal);

    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
}

public void invisible(View view){
    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que intentas acceder al botón usando el `findView` pero del **Activity**. Tienes que acceder al botón usando el **Item** actual del `viewPager`.

Con `viewPager.getItem().findViewById` deberia funcionar.

De todas formas nunca he usado así un ViewPager, sino que he creado un fragment por pantalla y dentro he aplicado la lógica necesaria.

Mírate el ejemplo de esta lib que viene explicado

https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator/tree/master/sample/src/main

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es que la inicialización del botón la realices dentro del método instantiateItem para que haga referencia a la vista en la que se encuentre

Comment: Hola, eso funciona pero entonces todo el código me queda en una activity. Yo quería trabajar el código de cada pantalla por separado.

Comment: Al hacer eso se pierde parte del sentido del ViewPager (el dinamismo de las pantallas); Si prefieres trabajar las pantallas por separado te recomiendo no usar ViewPager ya que tendrías que inicializar nuevamente el botón dentro del método instantiateItem.